# php errors from additional files

Tags: php

I'm having these errors:

> [12-Oct-2020 21:28:33 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load
> dynamic library 'xmlreader.so' (tried: ./xmlreader.so (./xmlreader.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> ./xmlreader.so.so (./xmlreader.so.so: cannot open shared object file:
> No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
> [12-Oct-2020 21:28:33
> UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
> 'xmlrpc.so' (tried: ./xmlrpc.so (./xmlrpc.so: cannot open shared
> object file: No such file or directory), ./xmlrpc.so.so
> (./xmlrpc.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
> directory)) in Unknown on line 0
> [12-Oct-2020 21:28:33 UTC] PHP
> Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'imagick.so'
> (tried: ./imagick.so (./imagick.so: cannot open shared object file: No
> such file or directory), ./imagick.so.so (./imagick.so.so: cannot open
> shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

And I can't seem to resolve them.  If I understand right, my php.ini file is trying to load these files and can't find them?  I have talked to my hosting tech people and I must not have climbed the chain of intelligence high enough because they didn't offer that much help.

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I don't have that much experience playing around on the server, but I've been using Putty and trying to figure out.

Here's what my php_info(); tells me:
[image]

Can I just do something to get these files to stop trying to load?  Apparently it can't find them.

Comment: I have looked in that php.ini file a number of times and I don't see any reference to those files.  I don't see anything mentioning a directory where they would be found.  But, it seems to me that php is automatically trying to load files found in a directory at the same level as the php.ini file, called "php.d"  I looked in there and found the exact laundry list of files.

Comment: So, I thought I might try to delete one and see if my error list (which matches those items perfectly...in my error.log file) but it told me I couldn't delete as it was "read-only."  I don't know a lot of command line stuff...just enough to scare myself.  I tried to do chmod 777 to the file I want to delete...wondering if that would give me more permission...but, while I did see it change to -rw-rw-r--, where before it was -rw-r--r-- it still wouldn't go away.  Same error about read-only.  Any suggestions?

Comment: How do I restart the server?  LOL